# After installing Thunar and removing nautilus lost my desktop icons and files

Tags: nautilus, thunar

I have installed Thunar instead of Nautlius. And now I have nothing on my desktop after  reboot. How to solve this problem? I have checked gnome-tweak-tool and "have file manager handle Destop" is ON. Please help. But they exist in Desktop folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thunar doesn't handle the desktop.

http://wiki.xfce.org/releng/4.10/roadmap/thunar#for_412_replace_xfdesktop_by_adding_a_thunarx_interface_for_desktop_extensions

You might get this script to work to do what you want, but you might be better of re-installing nautilus and using thunar as the file manager.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Script_to_change_Thunar_to_be_the_default_file_manager

Comment: Thanks, I have reinstalled nautilus. I cannot give you + because I have not reputation enough, sorry.

Comment: Not important to me - as long you've got the help you need:) Not sure if you can accept the answer.

Comment: @NadirNovruzov Please use the `accept` answer button to formally accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that Thunar is *currently* unable to manage your desktop.

You can re-install Nautilus, but I prefer using NEMO for this.

NEMO will remember exactly where you place your icons on your desktop from session to session.  Nautilus does not seem to do that.

Caveat:  Unless someone has found an answer that I have not, there is no way to hide the "Computer" and "Home" icons on the NEMO-managed desktop.  Clicking on either runs NEMO instead of Thunar.

To use NEMO:

After setting Thunar as your default file manager 
and uninstalling Nautilus, do two simple steps:

1) install NEMO and 2)  open a terminal and enter this:

gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true